# Mercurial / HG revset_filter / tag_filter not being applied

Tags: mercurial, concourse

I have a pipeline.yml defined as follows:

```
resources:
- name: source-code
  type: hg
  source:
    uri: ssh://user@server/project
    private_key: {{repo_private_key}}
    revset_filter: tag("re:\d.\d.\d")

jobs:
- name: project
  plan:
  - get: source-code
    trigger: true
```

My tasks are not listed. They are all defined under `trigger` above.

I set my pipeline with fly:

```
fly set-pipeline --target main --config pipeline.yml --load-vars-from parameters.yml --pipeline project
```

Now:

1) Committing a new revision with a tag matching `\d.\d.\d` (say, 1.1.1) and pushing it to `ssh://user@server/project` does not to trigger a new build. How long should I wait? Does Concourse pull remote info every x number of minutes? Should `revset_filter` result in all applicable revisions? I tried changing it to `last(tag("re:\d.\d.\d"))` with same results.

2) Triggering a job manually, through the web GUI or fly, pulls a non-matching ref. For example, here's the latest "matching" source code output:

```
author My Name <name@company.com>
author_date 2017-07-24 13:27:40 -0500
commit 0ba59f2ee956f6317fc257086026fac4e7c0d8de
message Added tag 1.8.8 for changeset 1392e7143f45
tags tip
```

This does not match `tag("re:\d.\d.\d")` - i.e., the last line should read `tags 1.8.8`.

Lastly, I tried using `tag_filter` with same results.

It seems to me that `revset_filter` and `tag_filter` are not being applied.

Comment: What version of concourse are you on? It looks like the `revset_filter` was a recent addition. Also, the commit message you say doesn't match says it is adding tag "1.8.8" which matched "\d.\d.\d" perfectly.

Comment: I'm running Concourse 3.3.2 through Docker. Looks like ```revset_filter``` should be supported in this version. Regarding the commit message - ```tag()``` filters only tags - not commit messages. If I run ```hg log -r 'tag("re:\d.\d.\d")'``` only commits that have a tag matching ```\d.\d.\d``` are returned - commit ```0ba59f2ee956f6317fc257086026fac4e7c0d8de``` not being one of them. The message for that commit might as well have been ```foobar``` - it makes no difference. Just a bad example due to how Hg works.

Comment: Are there any examples of either ```revset_filter``` or ```tag_filter``` working in the wild? Couldn't find anything through Googling.